# How to check if the facebook post is commentable

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-comments

I am fetching the Facebook news feeds through API. User can comment on a post from website. but some posts doesnot allow the comment like *Like Stories, add friend stories, change profile pic stories* etc

How I can check that if the post allow the comment or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `actions` property of the post when you retrieve it from the API will show if the current (whose access_token you're using) user can like or comment on the post, e.g.

`/20531316728_167191526758558`

Contains:

```
{
  "id": "20531316728_167191526758558", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Facebook", 
    "category": "Product/service", 
    "id": "20531316728"
  }, 
  "message": "Find your polling place on Facebook at http://bit.ly/Fbppl and then watch the nation vote in real time.", 
  "picture": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCD6BNbTzxhmwEq&w=90&h=90&url=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2FFacebookHackers-production%2Fissue4_data%2Fissue4_fb_og.png", 
  "link": "http://www.facebookstories.com/vote", 
  "name": "America Votes 2012", 
  "caption": "www.facebookstories.com", 
  "description": "Watch the nation vote in real time.", 
  "icon": "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v2/yN/x/aS8ecmYRys0.gif", 
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/167191526758558"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/167191526758558"
    }
  ], 
// (and more properties which aren't relevant
```